# MongoDB index strategy for BSON `_id` vs String `id`?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a question for the scholars.

```
2018-11-09T19:01:39.896+0100 [conn1851] query database.collection 
  query: { 
    $query: { 
      id: "5bb79a18293609212200cbe2" 
    }, 
    $orderby: { 
      _id: 1 
    } 
  } 
planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 } 
ntoskip:0 
nscanned:138476 
nscannedObjects:138476 
keyUpdates:0 
numYields:0 
locks(micros) 
r:127627 
nreturned:1 
reslen:497 
127ms
```

To me it looks like because I am not querying the `_id` with BSON then the index isn't used properly. Do I really have to create additional indexes for querying the database on the string value of the `_id` namely `id` or is it just the type mismatch or something?

These are the current indexes I have

```
> db.collection.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "database.collection"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "sport_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "sport_id_1",
        "ns" : "database.collection"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "sport_id" : 1,
            "updated_at" : -1
        },
        "name" : "sport_id_1_updated_at_-1",
        "ns" : "database.collection"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "external_ids.id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "external_ids.id_1",
        "ns" : "database.collection"
    }
]
```

I am currently on mongodb 2.6.12 and using mongoid v 2.5 i think.

This is part of what a document looks like:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("593a61de2936093a460004ca"), 
  "sport_id" : ObjectId("592eefe3293609345c000867")
  "id" : "593a61de2936093a460004ca", 
  "created_at" : ISODate("2017-06-09T08:52:46Z") 
}
```

Looks like all our documents are also saving the string representation of the `_id`. This is just horribly wrongly modeled huh?

I didn't create this mess but I will have to fix it. Any suggestions how to proceed from this? Looks like we are for unknown reasons duplicating the `_id` into an `id`. Should I just index that or is there a better fix? I might have to rewrite this question come to think of it...

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're doing. Do your documents have a separate `id` field?

Comment: Looks like it @JohnnyHK... How do I fix this mess?

Comment: Ideally you'd remove the `id` field from all your documents and stick to using `_id` everywhere instead.

Comment: Filtering by 'id' then sorting by '_id' implies 'id' is not unique. Is it correct? Before removing 'id' check if it is being used as a string anywhere, e.g. regexp or any other string manipulation functions. 2.6 cannot convert types runtime so it might be the reason to have the duplicate. Even better if you dig up your VCS for the commit that introduced the string 'id' - it may explain why it is here or confirm it is sae to remove.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBlex I'll get to the bottom of this before deleting the column. For now, making sure that all queries are done to the _id column seems to do the trick!